# Login to Instagram stuck in an endless "hourglass" (WP8.1 c#)

Tags: c#, xaml, instagram

I'm trying to integrate my app with Instagram using the following code:

```
        string startUrl = "https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=" + InstagramApiKey + "&redirect_uri=http://none&response_type=token";
        string endUrl = "http://none";

        Uri startUri = new System.Uri(startUrl);
        Uri endUri = new System.Uri(endUrl);

        WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAndContinue(startUri, endUri);
```

and after the last line of code my app shows the Instagram login page but it's kind of stuck right before it shows me the login and password fields.
Am I missing something?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in the last line is an example below

```
WebAuthenticationResult WebAuthenticationResult = await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(WebAuthenticationOptions.None, **startUri, endUri**);
if (WebAuthenticationResult.ResponseStatus == WebAuthenticationStatus.Success)
{
}
```

Comment: plz help me also im also have same issue i make instagram login but dont know what do next 
 public void ContinueWebAuthentication(WebAuthenticationBrokerContinuationEventArgs args)
        {
            WebAuthenticationResult result = args.WebAuthenticationResult;

            if (result.ResponseStatus == WebAuthenticationStatus.Success)
            {
}
like facebook we useing facebookclint . ParseOAuthCallbackUrl(callback);